# Should I still respond to html if view is rendered with javascript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ajax, reactjs

I have a Rails application integrated with react, my views are rendered with react, including the html (JSX). I noticed that I had a few `format.html` responses from back when my views were regular erb views, now that they are not, should I still respond to html just in case (even  though I don't see how a user can use my app if they javascript have disabled)?

Example :

```
 def destroy
    @comment.destroy
    respond_to do |format|  
      format.json { head :no_content }
      format.html { redirect_to @question, notice: 'Comment was deleted.' }
    end
  end
```

Can I get rid of the html responses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether to keep it or not is a personal choice. I sometimes do, but fewer LOC makes for cleaner code. To remove it you have several options. You can leave the `respond_to` as is and just remove the html eg:

```
def destroy
  @comment.destroy
  respond_to do |format|  
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

but you can also remove the `respond_to` from each action (even fewer LOC) with something like this:

```
# put this LOC at the top of your controller, outside of any action
respond_with :json

# then each action is much simpler... you just assume it's always json
def destroy
  @comment.destroy
  head :no_content
end
```

Comment: Great, so it's a personal choice, I get paranoid over these simple choices sometimes and make a big deal out of it. Thanks Taryn